# A binary classifier predicts only one type of class

Tags: machine-learning, generative-models, homework

This is an assignment question. Can someone someone give me some clue on how to get through:

> A generative approach is used for a binary classification problem and it turns out that the resulting classifier predicts *positive* at ***all*** points ***x*** in the input space. What can we conclude for sure? Check all that apply.
>
> - There are no negative points in the training set.
> - The positive points are spread out     over the space, while the negative  points are    concentratd in a small region.
> - There are fewer  negative points than positive points in the training set.
> - The density   of  positive points is greater than the density of  negative points    everywhere in   the    space.

You need to select points that apply out of those four bullet points. Thanks

Comment: Are we missing some more information?

Comment: 'There are fewer points than points in the training set' ... are you sure you got that right?

Comment: There are some edits to the questions, Thanks - @Aditya

Comment: Going wiith option `B,C`? Even `A` can be True( worst case)?

Comment: I have tried a lot of combinations but nothing work (got wrong each time) - @Aditya

Comment: I think 'generative approach' is the key information here. Looking into generative models might help you with the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

While training your binary classifier, check for class imbalance. That's the only way you can take any final decision about the test data. As you don't know the actual result of test data, therefore, you need to make sure the classifier is good enough to generalize any new data.